# D7: Batch resave menu items

Tags: routes, batch-operations

Is there a way to resave all items in a particular menu batch-style?

I'm trying to avoid saving each menu item manually, there are so many of them...

Comment: What menus are you saving?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a menu-specific function (that I know of) but you can use the aptly named [`menu_rebuild()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7) to rebuild the entire menu cache in one go.